# Url escaped characters and angular router

Tags: angular, angular-router

An email is sent by my backend with a dynamic evaluated string link with this syntax:

```
https://example.com/slug-foo-title;id=bar
```

My route component is configured to ignore the slug and evaluate the id param to know what to fetch.

But after the email is sent, the url string changes to `https://example.com/slug-foo-title%3Bid=bar` and then Angular router doesn't know how to deal with this.

Comment: the URL escape happens after your email is sent, or is it done by some library on your backend?

Comment: Also have you considered using the traditional notation instead of the matrix one, which has no value here?

Comment: The backend is node.js based (Firebase Cloud Functions) and the evaluated string is formatted like this: https://example.com/${urlify(event.title)};id=${event.id} so I'm guessing the character swapping is done by the third party mailing api (Mailjet). We use the matrix notation because it was the default usage for Angular router. This is a site in production so going back to traditional notation would be a bit of a pain...